# Laravel многие ко многим

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

Есть три таблицы в БД. Связь многие ко многим

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модели

**Sample.php**

```
public function services()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service');
}
```

**Service.php**

```
public function samples()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sample');
}
```

Если бы я хотел добавить записи в таблицу sample_service через модель Sample, то я бы написал так

```
public function sync_services(int $sample_id, Request $request)
{
    $sample=Sample::findOrFail($sample_id);
    $sample->services()->sync($request->input('service_ids', []));

    return $sample->services;
}
```

Т.е. передал бы массив с идентификаторами сервисов, которые хотел бы добавить. И всё бы ничего, если бы мне не нужно было добавить повторяющиеся сервисы. Т.е. всё работает, если `sync([1,2,3])`, но мне нужно `sync([1,2,2,3,3,3,3])`. Мне важно, чтобы в таблице `sample_service` было именно так - без столбца `quantity` и т.п., поскольку каждый отдельный сервис с таблице `sample_service` будет иметь статусы - время закрытия, например. Далее нужно будет обновлять некоторые поля таблицы `sample_service`. Так что, я подозреваю, придётся, наверное, заводить третью модель SampleService

```
class SampleService extends Model
{
    public function Sample()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Sample');
    }

    public function Service()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Service');
    }
}
```

А в граничащих моделях добавить

```
public function sampleService()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SampleService');
}
public function sampleService()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\SampleService');
}
```

Однако при таком подходе не могу получить данные из `sample_service` непосредственно в tinker:

```
$sample = App\Sample::first();
$sample->sampleService;
```

Получаю ожидаемую ошибку - у меня нет таблицы `sample_services`. У меня название в единственном числе - `sample_service`

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base
>   table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db7.sample_services' doesn't
>   exist (SQL: select * from `sample_services` where
>   `sample_services`.`sample_id` = 1 and `sample_services`.`sample_id` is
>   not null)'

Пробую в модели Sample.php в связи указать таблицу, но это не имеет эффекта и приводит к той же ошибке. Что не так и как быть?

```
public function sampleService()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\SampleService', 'sample_service');
}
```

Как это сделать в laravel 5.6?

Comment: Т.к. у вас планируется не просто intermediate-таблица для связи Many-to-Many, а таблица с дополнительными полями, то я вижу логичное выделение этой таблицы в нормальную сущность (SampleService, но я бы ещё подумал над названием). По поводу последней ошибки пока непонятно

Comment: @ZhukovRoman Я тоже об этом думал. Предполагаю, что т.к. это уже не просто intermediate таблица, то её нужно уже тогда называть во множественном числе. И тогда работать будет, наверное

Comment: После добавления названия таблицы в `belongsToMany` вы перезапускали tinker? Очень странно, что не подхватился этот параметр

Comment: Да, перезапускал. Я думаю, что дело в названии связи. belongsToMany для многие ко многим. И работает тогда всё через связующую таблицу. А тут нужно, похоже hasMany. Но в hasMany нельзя указать название таблицы - нет такой возможности. В итоге ошибки

Comment: Похоже, что единственный вариант - изменить название таблицы

Comment: В hasMany и не нужно указывать название таблицы, т.к. оно уже определено в другом классе.

Comment: Пропишите в SampleService - protected $table = 'sample_service';

Answer (score 1):

Может это то, что вам нужно:

```
public function services()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Service::class,
        'sample_service'
    )->withPivot('quantity')
        ->withTimestamps();
}

$sample->services()->sync([$id => $request->only(['quantity'])], false);
```